# Failed Partition

Tags: 13.04, partitioning

I have a computer with 5 years. And my OS stopped working so I was trying to install Ubuntu 13.04 in it. Everything was working until in the installation window it popped up a window saying "Failed to create swap partition 5". What can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You may have a problem with your drive.  Before you go trying to find another drive, and you don't have anything important on the current drive, you can try Darik's Boot And Nuke.

Its a utility that will completely erase your hard drive.  Its in ISO format, so one you [download](http://www.dban.org/) it, burn it to a CD, and boot from it, and just follow the onscreen instructions.

Once its done, try installing Ubuntu again.

Also, You can restart the installation, and select Something else create one partition format it as ext4 and mount it as /, and another one mounted as Swap.

[image]
[image]
[image]